# Cycle through images on hover and stop with last seen image

Tags: jquery, cycle

I have a bunch of 5 images which I cycle through on hover.

http://jsfiddle.net/9kxw7wpg/1/

```
jQuery(function($){

    // Cycle plugin
    $('.slides').cycle({
        fx:     'none',
        speed:   1,
        timeout: 500
    }).cycle('pause');

    // Pause & play on hover
    $('.slideshow-block').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('.slides').addClass('active').cycle('resume');
    }, function(){
        $(this).find('.slides').removeClass('active').cycle('pause');
    });

});
```

What I now like to achieve is that on mouseout not the black background should be visible again but the last image that was seen on hover.

Answer (score 1):

Trivially, you could just remove the `removeClass` function.

```
jQuery(function($){

  // Cycle plugin
  $('.slides').cycle({
    fx:     'none',
    speed:   1,
    timeout: 500
  }).cycle('pause');

  // Pause & play on hover
  $('.slideshow-block').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.slides').addClass('active').cycle('resume');
  }, function(){
    $(this).find('.slides').cycle('pause'); //altered
  });

});
```

But the black background is caused by your own CSS:

```
.slides{
  z-index:0;
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

So is it necessary at all to have `visibility:hidden` if you want to remove it ultimately?